# List embedded in another list with JSF 2, PrimeFaces and JSTL

Tags: list, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jstl

On a Facelets page I travel a list to display data in a `p:dataTable` (a PrimeFaces component).
This list itself contains another list that I travel using a `c:forEach` (JSTL).

The problem is that the data for the list that `c:forEach` should handle does not appear. When I access a specific element it works well, but not in a `c:forEach`.

Is it not possible to use an inner loop variable embedded in another loop?

Here's the page's code:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template_utilisateur.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">

                <h:form prependId="false" id="form">

                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>

                    <p:dataTable id="carsTable" var="car" value="#{histCommController.lc}" rowKey="#{car.id}"  
                                  selectionMode="single" >

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Expand rows to see detailed information
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column style="width:4%">
                            <p:rowToggler/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:48%">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                id
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:48%">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                date envoi
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.dateEnvoi}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:rowExpansion id="expanssion">
                            <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="width:300px;"
                                         styleClass=" ui-widget-content grid">

                                <h:outputText value="Model:" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Year:" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.etat}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.dateEnvoi}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Color:" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.dateLivraisonRecommande}" />

                            <h:outputText value="Fichiers : " />
                            <h:outputText value="::::::::::::" />


                            <h:outputText value="Fichiers 1 : " />
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.listFichiers.get(0).nom}" />


                            <c:forEach var="jjjjj" items="#{car.listFichiers}">
                                <h:outputText value="nom fichier 1 : " />
                            <h:outputText value="#{jjjjj.nom}" />
                            </c:forEach>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </p:rowExpansion>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are mixing so-called `build-time` and `render-time`  constructs.

`build-time` happens first, and everything that happens there can not make use of things that don't exist until `render-time`, which happens after.

In your case, the JSTL `forEach` is build-time, while the `car` var is made available by the render-time `dataTable`. The solution is to use a render-time construct for the inner looping. The best candidate for this is `ui:repeat`.

See also

- [Beware the Difference Between Build-Time and Render-Time Tags in Facelets](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-beware-difference-between)